# ReferenceError: Cannot access 'opacity' before initialization in react

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am trying to make my page blurry when click a button

here is my code:

```
const Wrapper = styled.div`
  opacity: ${opacity};
`;

const opacity = 1;

function App() {
  const [isShowing, setIsShowing] = useState(false);

  const openModalHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setIsShowing(true);
    opacity = 0.1;
  };

  const closeModalHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setIsShowing(false);
    opacity = 1;
  };
```

But I'm getting this error

> ReferenceError: Cannot access 'opacity' before initialization in react

Comment: You cannot reassign values to a variable declared as `const`. You need to replace `const` with `let/var`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const Wrapper = styled.div`
  opacity: ${opacity};
`;
```

Write the above code under `const opacity = 1;`

So:

```
let opacity = 1;
const Wrapper = styled.div`
  opacity: ${opacity};
`;
```

Actually to make it work, you need to add `opacity` as your component state so it renders again when the opacity changes.

```js
function App() {
    const [isShowing, setIsShowing] = useState(false);
    const [opacity, setOpacity] = useState(1);
    const Wrapper = styled.div`
        opacity: ${opacity};
    `;

    const openModalHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setIsShowing(true);
        setOpacity(0.1);
    };

    const closeModalHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setIsShowing(false);
        setOpacity(1);
    };
    ...
```

I guessed you use `Wrapper` in your `App` component.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way I can change opacity by on click? after changed I clicked and I got this error `TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.`

Comment: i updated my answer, this will fix your error but i dont think it will make your component work. you need to update your component. please post some more code of your App component

Comment: But it won't chage opacity when I clicked

Comment: Thank you so much! I solved my problem. Really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You can also make use of props, like this:

```js
const Wrapper = styled.div`
  opacity: ${({ isShowing }) => isShowing ? 1 : 0};
`;

const App = () => {
  const [isShowing, setIsShowing] = useState(false);

  return (
    <Wrapper isShowing={isShowing}>
       ...
    </Wrapper>

  )
}
```

This also makes it easier to reuse styled-components blocks when you don't need to defined them inside your components.

Or even use CSS-properties to keep the generated CSS-file smaller. For each prop-change, styled-components will generate a new CSS class with CSS, so keep in mind that your generated CSS can grow a lot if you're not careful.